# Proofs: [0,1] is closed in R, (0,1) is open in R.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking to check my rigour and understanding of these:

**S [0,1] is closed in R.**

A set S is closed if it contains all its limit points.

Alternatively, a set S is closed if $\forall_{\epsilon > 0}, \exists x \in S \text{ s.t. } B_\epsilon(x) \notin S \implies$ There exists some x for which we cannot draw an open ball around x which is contained within S.

At the upper bound, $x = 1$. 
For any $\epsilon > 0$, $1 + \epsilon \notin [0,1]$. 
Therefore, $B_\epsilon(1) \notin S$.

At the lower bound, $x = 0$. 
For any $\epsilon > 0$, $0 - \epsilon \notin [0,1]$. 
Therefore, $B_\epsilon(0) \notin S$.

Therefore, S is closed.

**S (0,1) is open in R**

A set S is open if it does not contain all its limit points.

Alternatively, a set S is open if $\forall_{x\in S}, \exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t. } B_\epsilon(x) \text{ is contained in } S \implies$ For all x in S, we can construct an open ball around x which is contained in S.

For $x \in (0,1)$, choose $\epsilon = \text{min}\{\frac{x}{2}, \frac{1-x}{2}\}$.
For $x \in (0,1)$, $x - \epsilon > 0, x + \epsilon < 1$.
Therefore, $B_\epsilon(x) \in S \ \ \forall_x$.
Therefore, S is open.

Where have I gone wrong and what can I do better?

Comment: Your criterion for closedness is wrong. Note that your argument also applies to $(0,1]$. Also, I think your definition of openness is wrong, since according to your definition $(0,1]$ is open, as it doesn’t contain $0$, which is a limit point.

Comment: Hmmm: I don't think I buy your alternative definition of closed. Note that $\mathbb Q$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$, yet any $x \in \mathbb Q$ would satisfy that definition.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist If I argued at the lower bound, would it then be complete?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I've added the lower bound!

Comment: @TheveshTheva it’s not about completeness of the argument. It is not the case that a set is closed whenever “there exists some $x$ for which we cannot draw an open ball...” I’ve given you an example of a set that meets your criterion but is not closed.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist that wasn't the argument I was making though. Rather, it was that for any $\epsilon$, there exists x such that we cannot draw an open ball. So it's not "some x", but rather "some x for all $\epsilon$".

(PS. I'm so sorry if i'm understanding you wrongly :/ )

Comment: @TheveshTheva Take the set $(0,1]$. Is it not the case that there exists some $x \in (0,1]$ for which we cannot draw an open ball (around $x$) contained entirely in $(0,1]$? I think your exercise rules out open sets (that is, sets that are not open satisfy this requirement), but note that not open does not imply closed.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I get it now! Would i be better off going for: [0,1] is closed if its complement is open? And are you satisfied with my proof for the open set?

Comment: That would work. I haven't checked your choice of $\epsilon$, but conceptually it appears to be correct (assuming your choice of $\epsilon$ does work). One thing to note is that "A set S is open if it does not contain all its limit points" is not true. A set that does not contain all its limit points is not closed, which is not the same as a set being open.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist got it, that's very helpful!